# SUM IFS equivalent for SQLite

Tags: sqlite

The below crashes my DB Browser. Essentially I am trying to sum sales ("sales") by a sales person ("name") that occurred between two dates ("beg_period" and "end_period") pulled from a separate table.

```
SELECT ta.name, ta.beg_period, ta.end_period, 
    (SELECT SUM(tb.sales)
        FROM sales_log tb
        WHERE ta.name = tb.name
        AND tb.date BETWEEN ta.beg_period AND ta.end_period
        )
    FROM performance ta
    ;
```

Comment: What do you mean *crashes my DB Browser*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nested query can be re-written as a single query with a standard join.

```sql
SELECT ta.name, ta.beg_period, ta.end_period, SUM(tb.sales)
FROM performance ta INNER JOIN sales_log tb
     ON ta.name = tb.name
WHERE tb.date BETWEEN ta.beg_period AND ta.end_period
GROUP BY ta.name, ta.beg_period, ta.end_period;
```

My guess is that the original query was okay (however inefficient), but DB Browser just didn't know how to interpret the subquery for whatever parsing it attempts, etc.  In other words, just because it crashed DB Browser doesn't mean that it would crash sqlite library.  Try another sqlite database manager.